# Connecting Exchange Online Fails when passing proxy and running in System PowerShell - TokenProvider Returns Object Reference Error

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory, office365, exchangewebservices

I was connecting Exchange Online using a PowerShell window that is opened with system access. I used PSExec on an elevated Command Prompt to open the System access PowerShell. Below is the command.

```
PSExec -i -s PowerShell
```

On the PowerShell, I imported the latest [Exchange Online Management PowerShell module version 2.0.3](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/ExchangeOnlineManagement/2.0.3). I use the app-based authentication described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/exchange/app-only-auth-powershell-v2?view=exchange-ps#setup-app-only-authentication.

There is one more website that shows how to connect with app-based authentication: https://o365reports.com/2020/07/04/modern-auth-and-unattended-scripts-in-exchange-online-powershell-v2.

Below are the commands used to connect to Exchange Online.

```
Import-Module .\ExchangeOnlineManagement
$sessopt = New-PSSessionOption -SkipCACheck -SkipCNCheck -SkipRevocationCheck -ProxyAccessType IEConfig
$certkey = ConvertTo-SecureString "<EnterCertificateKeyHere>" -AsPlainText -Force
Connect-ExchangeOnline -CertificateFilePath "pfx Certificate Path" -AppId <EnterAppIdHere> -Organization "domain.onmicrosoft.com" -CertificatePassword $certkey -PSSessionOption $sessopt -verbose
```

When running the above, it returns Object Reference error. I got excited and went on to find what the error is by decompiling the DLL files and found that inside the '`ExoPowershellGalleryModule.dll` -> `NewExoPSSession.cs`' of the Exchange module, the 'GetAccessToken' function which is called around line:308 causes this error. Any idea what makes the `Object reference not set to an instance of an object. System.Management.Automation.RemoteException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` error. Was the proxy not taken from IE?

I've set the proxy settings in IE using the below Powershell command-lets in system PowerShell.

```
Set-ItemProperty -Path 'HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings' -name ProxyServer -Value "ProxyServerAddress"
Set-ItemProperty -Path 'HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings' -name ProxyEnable -Value 1
```

Any help to resolve this is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If your using

```
PSExec -i -s PowerShell
```

Then the proxy information your entering for the user will have no effect because the local system account will have its own profile information. Also if the proxy needs authentication you also won't be presenting any Network credentials.

If you really want to run under the system account you could try using netsh to configure the proxy https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/microsoft-defender-atp/configure-proxy-internet but if you proxy need authentication this won't work.

Comment: Using Netsh also gives an error but this time it seems the Exchange module doesn't pick proxy from WinHttp.